# Typo3 - sys_history and re-do the operation inside it

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I am in typo3 10.4, and recently one of the tables of one of my extensions has been truncate (TRUNCATE Table).
Not having an immediate database, and having an empty table, I would like to know if there is a feature/plugin/extension in Typo3 that allows you to re-execute the operations stored in the sys_history.
Alternatively, an example of code that allows API side php Typo3 to manage the re-execution of instructions in that table.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to replay such stuff. Sorry for your loss :(